# Outlook 2007 CommandBarControl.Execute won't work

Tags: vba, outlook

I recently switched to Outlook 2007 and noticed that my VBA-macros won't work. I use the following code to open a new appointment-item (and fill it automatically). It worked perfect in Outlook 2003, but now the objCB.Execute just does nothing. I tried different control IDs and it only works for some, but I could not figure out why or why not for all.

```
Dim ex As Explorer
Set ex = Application.ActiveExplorer

If ex.CurrentFolder.DefaultItemType <> olAppointmentItem Then
    Set ex = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim objCB As CommandBarButton
Dim objAppt As AppointmentItem

Set objCB = ex.CommandBars.FindControl(, 1106)
If objCB Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

objCB.Execute
```

Security is set to lowest level.

Comment: This works fine here (I am using C#3/NET35/Outlook2007). Is there an error *upon* execution or is the control just not found (and this existing before the Execute) as expected?

Comment: FindControl works and returns the right control, but calling the Execute method yields no result whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Office 2007 you will find that not every Control ID will run via CommandBar.ExecuteMSO, despite being included in the published lists.   I have found that complex controls like Shape Galleries will never work but even some more simple ones have been left out for no apparent reason.

I have successfully worked around this using SendKey (inside VBA) or AutoIT (when SendKey is not enough) and selecting the control via keystrokes and sometimes mouse-clicks as necessary.

Comment: I'm trying it with SendKeys, but this creates new problems. The new appointment opens, but I can't get the ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.

Comment: Once your appointment opens, How about explicitly declaring an appointment oject and setting it to the ActiveInspector.CurrentItem?.  This worked for me:
Sub test()
    Dim appt As AppointmentItem
    Set appt = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Debug.Print appt.Body
End Sub

Comment: Did that, but the reference is Nothing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other quick ideas for you.  I'm out of my element here since I don't normally do Outlook code.  I keep busy in the other MS Office apps so I thought at least the tip about Control ID's not executing could help.  It sounds like you are close though - perhaps an Outlook coder can help...

Answer (score 0):

This response is not about VBA, in my recent investigation of this problem in general I have no reason to suspect it would not work. I am leaving this answer as a reference. Please take it or leave it as you will. Here is a [topic on the issue](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=616) as outlookcode.com.

*This works fine here (I am using C#3/NET35/NET4/Outlook2007)*

Before blaming the OOM right away on this issue I would first ensure that the issue is *really indeed* with the Execute call and not with the FindControl or other program flow. Also remember that these CommandBars can be affected by the use and/or other add-ins: manually view the tree (OutlookSpy or by code) to clear up any doubt. Also, I am unsure how VB handles implicit casts, as with the assignment. Make sure it isn't silently swallowing up an error condition.

```
// working C# as "proof"
int NEW_APPOINTMENT_ID = 1106;
var _button = commandBars.FindControl(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
    NEW_APPOINTMENT_ID, null, false);
try {
  // button is of type Office.Core.CommandBarControl or null
  if (_button != null) {
    _button.Execute();
  };
} finally {
  Util.ComRelease(ref _button); // My util, but you get the point
}
```

**Make sure to Com-Release buttons** -- Just like Items, do not rely on the RCW to take care of the references manually. It is easy to crash the add-in this way.

Comment: Your link just describes the exact same problem. FindControl works, Execute does nothing. But this depends on what control you want to invoke: Print preview or Today view work!